# Amazon Product Advertising API returns "SignatureDoesNotMatch" when request url contains "!"

Tags: vba, amazon-product-api

I made a VBA program that uses Amazon Product Advertising API. Usually it works well, but when the request url contains `!` or `(` the API returns error code `SignatureDoesNotMatch`. But, the signature and URL my program sends is completely the same with the one http://associates-amazon.s3.amazonaws.com/signed-requests/helper/index.html generates (so the generated url also gets the error).

The error is caused by `(, ), *, !` and `'`.

`` @ / [ ] { } + - = . , : ; \ | _ ? " # $ % & ^ ~ ` `` don't. (Seemingly they're simply ignored.)

Removing those characters from parameters is a solution. But if anyone knows the cause of the problem and/or better solution, please let me know.

[The program is here.](https://github.com/anarchiStraw/excel/blob/master/BookList) The entry point is "main.searchBookInfo" and "helper.getSignature" generates signature.

**Example:**

Unsigned URL:

```
http://ecs.amazonaws.jp/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIL7NZCKP32A32LQQ&AssociateTag=attentiveada-20&Author=&Operation=ItemSearch&Publisher=&ResponseGroup=ItemAttributes&SearchIndex=Books&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2011-12-03T20%3A26%3A16%2B0900&Title=!&Version=2011-08-01
```

String to sign:

```
GET
ecs.amazonaws.jp
/onca/xml
AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIL7NZCKP32A32LQQ&AssociateTag=attentiveada-20&Author=&Operation=ItemSearch&Publisher=&ResponseGroup=ItemAttributes&SearchIndex=Books&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2011-12-03T20%3A26%3A16%2B0900&Title=!&Version=2011-08-01
```

Signature:

```
fmQKEfrtYkdWoJNHUryWIPoybM%2FqzOdFFmlgrQkBS2E%3D
```

Comment: Please include relevant code snippets in the body of your question rather than linking off-site. Make your question self-contained.

Comment: Sorrry and thanks for advise. I'll be more careful next time.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this (`SignatureDoesNotMatch`) by **not** encoding the `!` character. So I'm going to assume that if you encode the `!` character before you sign then this will work. The same is probably true of the other characters although I didn't test them.

Just FYI, I **did** get results back when using `!` as a `Title` parameter for an `ItemSearch` operation.

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan.

I've found that the JavaScript component I'm using doesn't encode !, (, ) and * which the Amazon API expects to be encoded.
So I replace them like this:
`Function urlEncode(str As String) As String
  Dim sc As Variant
  Set sc = CreateObject("ScriptControl")
  sc.Language = "Jscript"
  urlEncode = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(sc.CodeObject.encodeURIComponent(str), "!", "%21"), "(", "%28"), ")", "%29"), "*", "%2A")
End Function`
Then requests containing those chars worked.
Sad to say, their results were all the same as when I ommitted those chars from request string.